# Interval selection algorithm with 2 overlappings at most

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/interval-selection), in which N (N<=1000) intervals are given, and the algorithm should compute the (size) largest subset of intervals such that no three intervals in the subset share a common point. Right now I am looking only for a **Dynamic Programming** algorithm.

My idea was to sort the intervals by finishing time and then to  consider the following subproblem:
A[i] - the solution to the problem (i.e max. number of intervals) using only the first i intervals.

And now my question is about the recurrence: if the ith interval is taken, then I can't figure out the recurrence.

Could someone explain where I did wrong (was it the subproblem definition or do I simply miss something at the recurrence subproblem)?

---

**EDIT (new idea?)**
After some research, I have found this [DP solution](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/cs423/lectures/dynamic-programming-4up.pdf) for the general Job Selection algorithm. So the next idea would be to have the `q` array, where `q[i]` = the index of the last interval that has no overlapping with the i-th interval. 
And then for sure, the formula for computing A[i] when the i-th interval is taken would be something like (note the missing part):

```
A[i] = 1 + A[q[i]] + [missing-part];
//1 stands for the i-th interval
//A[q[i]] stands for the solution of the intervals that do not overlap with with the i-th interval
//[missing-part] is the maximum number of intervals from the intervals that overlap with the i-th intervals that are safe to be added.
```

The question remain: how to compute the missing part?

---

**EDIT (greedy solution, not the wanted solution)**
The greedy solution is pretty straightforward, very similar to the [Job Selection Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_selection_problem), with the additional check that when adding a new interval, there must remain no unprocessed intervals that break the condition of the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this direction will work, because it might be that when adding a new interval, we can't add to the previous solution but instead have to change things completely.

Comment: @redtuna I am sure that only the A[i] is not enough, but... do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Sure, I'd try a search algorithm with a greedy heuristic.

Comment: Yes, I would try greedy only after finding a DP solution, as the problem is listed there in the category "Dynamic". Probably there is a guaranteed solution with greedy, not only a heuristic.

Comment: @AndreiI Did you able to solve this problem?

Comment: @Vinay I solved it with a the greedy solution. No solution With dynamic programming so far.